# Sampling a signal with halved frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, sampling, sampling-theory

I have this signal $ x(t) = sin ( 2 \pi f_0 t ) $ , with $ T_c = \frac{1}{f_0} $ and I have to find $ x_\delta (t) $ and the reconstruction signal. first I found that $ f_c > 2 f_s $ so the Nyquist condition isn’t verified and there’s aliasing. After, I found that $ x_ \delta (t) = 0 $, because $\sin(2\pi)=0$. Now I know that the reconstruction signal $ x_{rec} (t) $ is the inverse Fourier transform of $ X(f) $. I found that $ X(f) = \frac{i}{2} \delta (f + f_c) - \frac{i}{2} \delta ( f - f_c ) $ but my book write that’s $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x(t)  = \sin(2\pi f_0 t)$ and sampling period be $T_s = \frac{1}{f_0}$. So we have $$p(t) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t-nT_s)$$Where $p(t)$ is sampling function. Multiplying $x(t)$ and $p(t)$ gives us $$x_p(t) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty}x(nT_s)\delta(t-nT_s)$$
In this case $x(nT_s) = \sin(2\pi n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So $x_p(t)$ is identically zero which implies $X_p(j\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$:  $$X_p(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x_p(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}0 \ dt = 0$$Therefore the reconstructed signal using lowpass filter will be identically zero.

Comment: I understand up to $ x_p (t) = 0 $. And now I understand that is more simple say that if $ x_p (t) = 0 $ so also $ X_p (iw) = 0 $ But why I didn’t obtain the same result using $ X(f) $ I previously calculated? I should have $ X_p (iw) = f_c X (f -k f_c) $ and I should obtain the same yours result if my Fourier transform is correct. I don’t understand where’s the error? thanks !

Comment: @ElenaMartini Actually I tried to understand your answer but it wasn't clear to me. Please explain more about your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I’m Italian and not so good with English.. first of all I obtained , as you , that $ x_\delta (t) $ (you called it $ x_p (t) ) is = 0 $. You said that since $ x_p(t) = 0 $ so also $ X_p(f) = 0 $ but is this always verified? How I can demonstrate this ? I tried to demonstrate this using the formula of $ X_p (f) $ that I wrote up and using the formula of $ X(f)$  that I wrote on the question but I didn’t obtain $ X_p (f) = 0 $

Comment: @ElenaMartini Yes, it's always true. Just use the definition for the Fourier transform. Integral of zero function is equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!

Comment: @ElenaMartini You're welcome.